# how to handle two button in a single form?

Tags: jquery, html, forms, button

```
<input type="submit" value=""  id="button1"/>
<input type="submit" value="" id="button2" />
```

I have two button in a single form. At a time only one button shows on the client side. It is done in jquery. But 'return' key works only for one button the previous one. For next button i have to use mouse. Does any one have any idea about that? I come up with a solution..
    
    
But how to maintain focus on button1?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if only one button shows at any time, you could just use one button and change the name (and value) property instead of showing / hiding one or the other. Would that work?